# Getting an error "number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length"

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, strptime

I'm trying to convert a record into a date and time format using the `strptime` function. However, I'm not sure why I'm getting the error:

> number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length.

I tried to check the length of the record using the `length` function but both have the same length.

```
data <- DT
head(data[6])
#                column
# 1 2014-12-22 23:53:48
# 2 2014-12-22 23:20:34
# 3 2014-12-22 23:20:30
# 4 2014-12-22 23:20:16
# 5 2014-12-22 23:20:07
# 6 2014-12-22 23:05:49

data[,6] <- as.character(data[,6])

temp_file <- matrix(0,nrow=nrow(data))

temp_file[1] <- strptime(data[1, 6],"%F %T")
# Warning message:
# In temp_file[1] <- strptime(data[1, 6], "%F %T") :
#   number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

length(temp_file[1])
# [1] 1

length(data[1,6])
# [1] 1

length(strptime(data[1, 6], "%F %T") )
# [1] 1
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: That is actually a good question. This isn't an error, rather a warning, but the result you get is wrong, so you could consider it as an error. The reason this is happening is because of the definition of a `matrix` in R, which can only get atomic vectors. When you are trying to pass `strptime` to the matrix, it's class is `"POSIXlt" "POSIXt"`, thus it is unclasses it and thus returns a list of its attributes (which length is larger than 1), i.e., `unclass(strptime(data[1,1],"%F %T"))`. The first value is `48` seconds. This is exactly what you have in `temp_file[1]` now.

Comment: Thus, either use `data.frame`  instead of a `matrix` or try to convert your vector to atomic, for example: `temp_file[1] <- as.character(strptime(data[1,1],"%F %T"))`

Answer (score 0):

You can transform character vector into datetime format using `ymd_hms` function of `lubridate` package:

```
library(lubridate)

# data frame simulation
structure(list(X1 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), X1.1 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), 
    X1.2 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), X1.3 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), 
    X1.4 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), date_time_char = c("2014-12-22 23:53:48", 
    "2014-12-22 23:20:34", "2014-12-22 23:20:30", "2014-12-22 23:20:16", 
    "2014-12-22 23:20:07", "2014-12-22 23:05:49")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))

# transform from character to datetime
data$date_time <- ymd_hms(data[, 6])
data[, 7]
```

Output:

```
[1] "2014-12-22 23:53:48 UTC" "2014-12-22 23:20:34 UTC" "2014-12-22 23:20:30 UTC" "2014-12-22 23:20:16 UTC"
[5] "2014-12-22 23:20:07 UTC" "2014-12-22 23:05:49 UTC"
```

N.B. Really nice comment by David Arenburg:

> That is actually a good question. This isn't an error, rather a
>   warning, but the result you get is wrong, so you could consider it as
>   an error. The reason this is happening is because of the definition of
>   a matrix in R, which can only get atomic vectors. When you are trying
>   to pass strptime to the matrix, it's class is "POSIXlt" "POSIXt", thus
>   it is unclasses it and thus returns a list of its attributes (which
>   length is larger than 1), i.e., unclass(strptime(data[1,1],"%F %T")).
>   The first value is 48 seconds. This is exactly what you have in
>   temp_file[1] now.